# I want to design a joule thief circuit with input of 2mV and output 1.5V

Tags: transistors, mosfet, design, joule-thief

I want to design a joule thief circuit having an input of 2mV and output of 1.5V.
I searched for low input joule thief (JT) and I found that by using ALD110800/ALD110900 (they have zero threshold voltage) I can design one. But the problem is that I cannot find these MOSFETS in my city and I don't have time to order these online. So is there any other MOSFET or transistor that I can use for my JT?
Also can you tell me the design formula's for JT.

Comment: This is a very very very very hard (~= impossible) task to do well. You need to tell us the what and why of what you are trying to do. | Q1: What is the source of your 2 mV? Q2: Why 2 mV and why not 10 mV or 0.1 mV or ...? At such low levels the nature of the source is  crucial. Q3: What is the power level? This too is crucial. At 2 mV-> 5V the step up ration is 2500:1. The current step down is 1:2500. Power levels from 2 mV sources are usually in the microwatt range - usually mW at best. At  5V, 1 mW = 200 uA.  Is that what  you are dealing with? || MUCH MORE INFORMATION NEEDED.

Comment: You wrote  "I can design one". Then you asked "can you tell me the design formula's for JT".  In engineering the capability to design means among many other details the ability to build or extract from sources the needed formulas. We will not be the source before you show also some own effort. Sorry.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I am just trying a DIY for my own interest. Its not necessary to use 2mV, it can be more like 50mV. The output should be more than 1V but 1.5V seems better. I have no concern about the current and power, all I need is 1.5V output. And I was looking to design it but could not found the design equations for this. And I want to use human heat as source.

Comment: @user287001 I am really sorry if my question hurt you. But I searched for this but could not found much useful. All I found was the zero threshold MOSFET. I am not much experienced in the field of electronics. After the dead end I posted my question here so that I might found something and continue my research.

Comment: Instead of trying to design a discrete solution for harvesting energy from millivolt sources, I'd recommend checking out the field of "Energy Harvesting", there are several companies working in this area and in fact the [LTC3107](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3107.html) from Analog Devices is *specifically designed* to work with thermo-electric sources down to 20mV

Comment: Here's a plausible looking writing of sub-20mV input oscillators. http://www.dicks-website.eu/fetosc/enindex.htm. Their inductors very likely make high enough pulses. Insert a not too much loading rectifier and capasitive storage  for the output DC power. The fet is a depletion type JFET which conducts with Vgs=0. The transformer generates the needed negative Vgs to shut down the current temporarily.

Comment: @Sam, that AnalogDevice’s **LTC3107** is an ingenious design, but it is quite rare & odd - as the application already is, by the way. I found a similar from ST - **SPV1050**, also rare and hard to find. The search for thermoelectric energy generators is not a new thing - on a past job we made a prototype work using several Peltier devices in series to reach a reasonable voltage. After 20+ years, and just as a curiosity, have you ever seen other designs addressing these *ultra-low voltage energy harvesting* solutions - maybe using something not so hard to find?